# How do you initialize a Blazor server application database with Admin user on very first launch?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I would like to know the best practice about initialization the application and create an Admin user with a hashed pass at first execution of the application. I am new in Blazor but I remember that in old time where I installed some forum in php they used to have a page for init the database and after execution was autodeleted, what about in Blazor ? Thank you everyone for the help.

Comment: You have better to looks for "seeding database with user account in asp.net core". Since the answer has nothing much common with blazor itself.

Comment: @Alamakanambra thank you so much for the tip, I will do as suggest

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure whether you already get the solution yet, I just shared my test result along with related document with you. My idea is that your requirement is making sure we will have an admin account before we running the app so that we could have an account to sign in. Within the default template, we already had a register page for us to create user. I assume you might want to have some other init feature within your app, so I think we require a method to include all the preparation in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are owning an asp.net core 3.1 application, we [have document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-another-app-to-add-users-2) which demonstrate how to add init function to create users before the app is running. We only need to create a method which creating the user and call this method in Program.cs.

In blazor app, it should be similar. Assuming we are having a new blazor web app in .net 8 and choose the authentication type as `Individual Accounts` so that we already have scaffold files for default indentity and the database, we need to run `Update-Database` command before running the app. More details can be seen [in the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-another-app-to-add-users-2).

Then we could create an Init method and write logic to check if we had "admin" count before running the app.

Let's create a class like below, and call the init method in Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Linq;

namespace BlazorAppIdenetity.Data
{
    public class InitData
    {
        public static void Initialize(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            var admin = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "admin").SingleOrDefault();
            if (admin != null) {
                return;
            }

            var hasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "admin",
                PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "1qaz!QAZ")
            };
            context.Users.Add(user);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var dbcontext = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        InitData.Initialize(dbcontext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tiny for the useful information ! I guess it will work even on Asp Net core 6 so I will try this solution that seems quite what I asked for.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply and I'm glad to assist you : )

Comment: Hi @Tinywang I did check the documentation for the net 6 but I did not found any init function before the launch of application.

Comment: `any init function before the launch of application` -> hi, what we have is a function executed at first when the app is launching, if we need a function executed before running an app, then we need another app. And what .net 6 documents share is like this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-another-app-to-add-users-1

Comment: what  we have for your requirement, is something like seeding database as what Alamakanambra said. Or something like "running a method in Program.cs"

Comment: Ok so I guess I understnd what you mean, I will check then what's the best solution in my case, if creating an app just for doing a simple addition and starting configuration of the database or work on the same app using other method.

Comment: that's great, and if you choose to have another app to execute the init function/script or sth else, there's also many ways, for example we might create a powershell script for it, but I'm not an expert on that, I can't provide much help on it. anyway, you can feel free to follow up here.