ASP.NET Core 8 Web API and Angular 18
How can I configure MigrationMethod in Program.cs so that the migration will update itself?
I want my migration to be launched on app.Run();
I added the call to my function in Program.cs :
SeedDatabaseAndMigrate(app);

Here's the function that I want to use for the migration
async void SeedDatabaseAndMigrate(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<TestDbContext>();

    try
    {
        // Apply migrations
        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();

        // Seed initial data
        //StoreContextSeed.SeedAsync(context).Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Database migrated and seeded successfully.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error seeding database: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}


Running the database migration and data initialization might bring issue when the application is running multiple instances, like Azure app service auto scale out. But if you  want to do it, then it's also possible to run a method in Program.cs so that the method will be run when the application just starts, for example this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77906842/14574199   Pls correct me if I misunderstand your concerns.

The code you used works fine. So I guess you may have some exception or other issue. Few notes here, you should watch out for:

async void - it swallows your exceptions, and the actual Task cannot be awaited. Maybe that is why you don't see the results before the app is run. There's nothing to await, so migration is just started, but your app startup proceeds without awaiting it.

If you place call to your method after call to app.Run() it won't be executed, as it won't reach it before actual app is run. So you must be sure you call it before that invocation.



Thx. But it is not working!
